# Google Map not rendering on MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm facing problem in rendereing google map on Mapview, In my main layout,I have a login screen and view flipper. In ViewFlipper i have 2 layout, First layout gives description about my company and second layout i have my mapview. so when i flip from my first layout of Viewflipper, Mapview is displayed but google maps not getting rendered on mpaview.

I have specified all permission related to Map.

Comment: Code!! have you included Gmap keys to show Google Maps

Comment: it might be the issue with the debug key, you can create a new debug key and hope it will work Thanks

Comment: Did you look through other questions on here with similar problems? Your map key is most probably not correct.

Comment: Everything is fine , i tried demo porject with same key with out any other layout, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Surely your Mapkey is not correct, or your are using key generated on some other system.

Comment: SIM is there, I did a POC with same Map Key where i used only Map in the layout , even that works fine. Please help me